# Is it possible to use Android to control relays?

Tags: android, driver, hardware

This isn't a highly technical (or specific) question. I just want to know if it is possible to use an android app to control 12V relays.

I want to use this running android:
http://www.mini-box.com/pico-SAM9G45-X

with this touchscreen attached:
http://www.mini-box.com/INNOLUX-7-TFT-with-touchscreen

I want to mount this in my car and write a simple android application that can be used to control my lighting in the car (via several 12V relays). I have a lot of background programming in many different languages, so I am not worried about the application part. However, I have very little experience using software to control hardware.

Any ideas for this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You would have to port the OS to the hardware, writing your own drivers along the way - retagged your post to get the right attention :)

Comment: The hardware is capable of running Android off a microSD I believe. Check the wiki here:http://arm.mini-box.com/index.php?title=Main_Page#SOFTWARE

Thanks for the re-tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to get Android running on your Pico board. There are several releases of Android ported to Pico for you to play with here: http://arm.mini-box.com/index.php?title=Releases

Once you accomplish this, I recommend wiring up an ADK board to the pico and using that to interface with your relays. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html The most popular and widely documented ADK board designs are based on Arduino or PIC chips so if you have experience with either I don't think it will be too much trouble. Writing the application would entail writing a program on the ADK which listens for input from an Android app which you also create and reacts accordingly. There's a handful of good information you can find with google searches to help you out and also some dedicated discussion groups.

Alternatively, it may be possible to use the remaining unused pins on the Pico to talk to your relays. I don't know for certain though if the Android ports support this or not.

It should be a fun project to keep you busy for a couple weeks. Good luck, and be sure to write up some information on it if you get it working!

Comment: Great info! Thanks a lot, I think one of the ADK boards will be answer, I had not heard of them before. Time to start buying and experimenting!

Answer (score 1):

you can find so many relay boards which come with wifi and they have their own app. which you can install in your Android phone or PC or iphone(you can find a ios app for same board). and you can also modify apps according to your choice and there are products which come with input pins also so you can control lights or anything else using those input. you can check this product check this [Android control realy](https://www.controlanything.co.in/Relay/Device/R8xPL_Web-i_Androi) and there are so many products available.